# Что такое темплейт в php?

Tags: php

```
$row_tmpl = <<<EOFHTML
<tr>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>%s</td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' value="%s">
    </td>
</tr>
EOFHTML;
```

Comment: темплейт, ну и название :) template - шаблон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя вина, пардон : ) Это правильно называть не темплейтом, а «[форматом](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)».

Смысл в том, что в строке есть специальные вставки, напр. `%d` (место для числа), `%s` (место для строки) - подробнее по ссылке выше. И потом функциями [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php), или [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) в эти места подставляются значения.

Из примера в документации:

```
$num = 5;
$location = 'дереве';

$format = '%d обезьян сидят на %s';
printf($format, $num, $location);
```

Выведет "5 обезьян сидят на дереве".

А магия с `<<<EOFHTML` называется "[heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)" — удобный способ ввести многострочный текст. Например, пишешь:

```
$RiL = <<<PUSHKIN
В темнице там царевна тужит,
А бурый волк ей верно служит;
Там ступа с Бабою Ягой
Идёт, бредёт сама собой,
PUSHKIN;
```

И четверостишье оказывается в переменной `$RiL`, как если бы его заключили в двойные кавычки. (Важно, чтобы закрывающая метка, в этом примере - `PUSHKIN;` - начиналась прямо с начала строки, а после ; не было никаких пробелов.)